# Why is this not printing the values from the txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, filestream

Here is a snippet of library.h
btw this a snippet of library.h

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #pragma warning (disable:4267)
 #pragma warning (disable:4311)
 #pragma warning (disable:4313)
 #pragma warning (disable:4244)
 #pragma warning (disable:4996)
 #pragma warning (disable:4800)
 #pragma warning (disable:4018)
 #pragma comment( lib, "library.lib" )
 using namespace std;
```

Library.h is a header file that is a graphical library that also contains most of the C++ library already included, I need to print all the values from database1.txt, btw sorry if my code looks like a disaster have  not coded C++ in for four years.

```
#include <library.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

struct st {
double month;
double day;
double year;
double social;
string fname;
string lname; 
double address;
}roll [14];
void rawr (st dat);

void main()
{
ifstream meow("database1.txt");

{
if (meow.fail())
cout << "Not enough data in the file!, NOOB";
}
int n;
while (meow){
double d;
string e, f;
double  g;
double a, x, c;
meow>>a;
meow>>x;
meow>>c;
meow>> d;
meow>> e;
meow>> f;
meow>>g;
cout << a<<" "<<x<<" "<< c<< " "<<d<<" "<<e<<" "<<f<<" "<<g;
for (n=0; n<14; n++)
{
stringstream(a)>> roll[n].month;
stringstream(x)>> roll[n].day;
stringstream(c)>> roll[n].year;
stringstream(d)>> roll[n].social;
stringstream(e)>> roll[n].fname;
stringstream(f)>> roll[n].lname;
stringstream(g)>> roll[n].address;  
}
for (n=0; n<14; n++)
rawr (roll[n]);
} 
}
void rawr (st dat)
{
    cout << dat.month<<" "<<dat.day<<" "<< dat.year<< " "<<dat.social<<" "<<dat.fname<<" "<<dat.lname<<" "<<dat.address;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You issue *may* be due to incorrect definition of `main`.  The `main` function returns an `int`.  Always.

Comment: If this compiles its by sheer luck, as `std::ifstream` requires `<fstream>` which is not in your include list. Nor is `std::string` being fulfilled by `<string>`, or any of the io-stream operations to `cin` or `cout` via `<iostream>`

Comment: they are included in library.h

Comment: Advice:  **Always** include header files you are using; don't rely on other libraries or other include file dependencies.

Comment: BTW, if the file fails to open, your program will continue executing.  Maybe use an `else` clause or a `return` statement to prevent the code from executing when the open fails.

Comment: Why are you reading in the month, day and year as `double`?  I've never seen a month 3.14 or a day 7.683 or a year 1925.1748294.

Comment: Does this code compile?  I don't show constructors for [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream)  that use `double` in the consructor.  Also, why are you using `stringstream` and not doing something like `roll[n].month = a;`?

Comment: I was using roll[n].month =a; before, forgive me if it seems confusing as I have changed the c++ libraries within the windows SDK

Comment: I was using doubles because of how some of the values are stored

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get your simple program working before worrying about library headers.  There are too many issues with your program.  Let's prefer a simpler approach:

```
struct Record
{
  unsigned int  month;  // Month's can't be negative nor floating point.
  unsigned int  day;
  unsigned int  year;
  std::string   social;  // Social has form xxx-xx-xxxx, so it can't be floating point.
  std::string   first_name;
  std::string   last_name;
  std::string   address;
};
```

To make input from a stream easier, let's over load `operator >>`:

```
struct Record
{
  // Same as above
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.month;
  input >> r.day;
  input >> r.year;
  input >> r.social;
  input >> r.first_name;
  input >> r.last_name;
  input >> r.address;
  return input;
}
```

Overloading `operator>>` will make the input a lot easier:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::ifstream database_stream("database1.txt");
  if (!database_stream)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error opening database1.txt\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  //  This code will be execute if the file was opened successfully.
  std::vector<Record> database;
  Record r;
  while (database_stream >> r)
  {
    database.push_back(r);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

No need for `stringstream`.  The input functionality of the `Record` has been *encapsulated* into the `Record` object, thus simplifying the `main` function.

The `operator<<` can also be overloaded in a similar manner in the `Record` struct.  This will simplify the `main` function as well.

**Edit 1:  Refactoring**
The `month`, `day` and `year` can be *refactored`into a separate`Date` class (which may be reused in other assignments):

```
struct Date
{
  unsigned int month;
  unsigned int day;
  unsigned int year;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Date& d);
  friend std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& output, const Date& d);
};

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& input, Date& d)
{
  input >> d.month >> d.day >> d.year;
  return input;
}

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Date& d)
{
  output << d.month << "\t" << d.day << "\t" << d.year;
  return output;
}
```

Your `Record` then simplifies to:

```
struct Record
{
  Date  d;
  std::string   social;  // Social has form xxx-xx-xxxx, so it can't be floating point.
  std::string   first_name;
  std::string   last_name;
  std::string   address;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
```

};

And your `Record::operator>>` method simplifies to:

```
std::istream&  
operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.d >> r.social >> r.first_name >> r.last_name >> r.address;
  return input;
}
```

If you put your `Date` structure into separate files, you can reuse it by including the header file into other source files and then add the `Date.cpp` file to the project.  No need to waste time rewriting or testing it. :-)

Comment: Forgive me, but the text file that it is reading from has a social with no dashes, but thank you for simplifying it for me

Comment: How do I merge values lets persay from another txt file that has the same person but additional values

Comment: Let's think on this.  If a person has additional values, you will need to add those attributes to your structure.  You will also need to *search* the database before appending to it.  Hmmm, speaking of databases, any reason you are not using one?

Comment: If there are optional fields, you will need to *think* of an algorithm or method on how to handle it, like reading the whole line first, then parsing the text.

Comment: I am using one, am I not?